# how can I download lyrics for audio files?

Tags: audio, mp3-player

In the past and in others platforms I was used to plays mp3 and downloads txt/lrc lyrics from internet

how can I download lyrics for lacally stored mp3 files?

The app minilyrics for android is failing on my device and also it seems that was removed from Play

Comment: Have you tried https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.musixmatch.android.lyrify

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Good suggestion! It's the very music player I've been using for years, but I'd like to note that I'm running a cracked version of 6.8.0 found online, instead of the vanilla 7.x from Play, due to ads/offline lyrics and the ugly new look.

Comment: @iBug I prefer this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geecko.QuickLyric

Comment: thanks @ReddyLutonadio , I tried the (opensource) Quicklyric and it find a lot of txt and syncronized lyrics. But i don't like  that lyrics are stored in its own database instead of a text file in the mp3 folder. So I have too much dependency of this app and the android platform.